# Flask disable JSON response escaping

Tags: python, json, flask

I am trying to pass a url in a json response for a REST API using flask and when I try to send a url it goes from "https://www.google.com/" to /\ on the slashes. How can I prevent this from happening?

Already tried decoding to utf-8. Already tried passing as a variable.

```
def login():
    return json({"url": "https://www.google.com/"})
```

Not change slashes in url.

Comment: That's... improbable. Forward slashes don't need escaping in JSON -- only backslashes do -- and I've never seen an engine that tries to escape forward slashes (since doing so would make its behavior contrary-to-spec). Could you provide a *complete* [mcve] -- that is, the shortest code code someone can run themselves *without needing to add or change anything* to see the problem?

Comment: That said, what is the `json` function you're using here? Where did it come from? If you included your `import`s, we might already know, but as it is, the question isn't complete enough to know what you're trying to do even as-is.

Comment: Which library are you using? (ie. where is the `json` function from?)

Comment: You should use [flask-restplus](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use built in json response method.

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/login/')
def login():
    return jsonify({"url": "https://www.google.com/"})
```